# Get value from People Editor Control?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, peoplepicker

I have created a visual WebPart contains a people Editor control to pick the Manager Name(infact only one name).
The control is working fine but i would like to store the particular value to a variable using code during the button click . how can i achive this ? any help?

Answer (score 6):

Hope this code is helpful for you..

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   ….
   //where userPicker is Id of People picker control
   PickerEntity pe = (PickerEntity)userPicker.Entities[0];  
   string username = pe.Description;
   …
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer.Thanks for the idea. 
Below is the code which works fine for me.

```
    SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;

    SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists["myList"].Items;

    SPListItem item = listItems.Add();

    string[] UsersSeperated = pplEditor.CommaSeparatedAccounts.Split(',');

    SPFieldUserValueCollection UserCollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();

    foreach (string UserSeperated in UsersSeperated)

       {

    mySite.EnsureUser(UserSeperated);

    SPUser User = mySite.SiteUsers[UserSeperated];

    SPFieldUserValue UserName = new SPFieldUserValue(mySite, User.ID, User.LoginName);

    UserCollection.Add(UserName);

   }

item["people"] = UserCollection;

item.Update();
```